# Image Server Performance

Tags: image, mongodb, couchdb, failover

I have read many questions/comments regarding saving the image in DB or file system on server side. However i'm still confused. For now I allow user to upload image (limit to 10MB) and I save the image in the server folder and serve the image via apache context path configuration pointed to that location. However, due to the numbers of image and high load. We want to provide load balancing and fail over functionality. So I have 2 options.

1. Add code to replicate the uploaded image to all servers or using rsync to do that.
2. Using CouchDB or MongoDB and save the image as attachment of an document. So I have out of the box replicate functionality.

Can anyone show me the pros/cons of these approach. Can CouchDB/MongoDB have the same read performance compared to file system ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also store files in distributed file system. The benefit over DB supported image server is you do not have to alter the application. Obviously, storing all the data the same way, including images, may be a benefit for you, but changing architecture for already working system may also be problematic.

For example, [GlusterFS](http://www.gluster.org/) may be installed on top of "normal" file system to give you distributed features minimizing changes to the system itself. It is supposed to support via its plugins (translators) all the feature you would potentially expect from cloud system: replication, load balancing, stripping of files into relocated parts and fail-over.

Comment: Yes, I have also look at some opensource such as mogileFS, GlusterFS or CODA however, it tooks long learning curve to begin and sometimes I don't know where to start because the lack of document. My simple solution still works just fine, but problem arise when I want to scale out. Using CounchDB or MongoDB give me the scalability I need.  However, still afraid of storing images in the DB because of its bad reputation.

Answer (score 0):

> Can CouchDB/MongoDB have the same read performance compared to file system ?

No, there will be lag between file system timers and database timers, this is an unfortunately reality.

I have no idea of your current setup, load and performance so I cannot really advise on what to do, however, Apache isn't really a good image server anyway.

Your best bet might be to look into a CDN cache for your images.

Comment: Dear Sammaye, my application just allow user to upload the image(tif,jpg,png) and return the URL to be used later on. So I save the uploaded image on the server side location such as /home/hieulam/images and I add one context root to point to that location to serve the image. Can Nginx increase the performance compared to Apache.